# Double Negation in Korean "있어요" vs "없지는 않아요"

Tags: difference, negation

If you contrast

> (1) 나는 여자친구가 **있어요**. I have a girl friend.

with

> (2) 나는 여자친구가 **없지는 (없진) 않아요**. I have a girl friend.

the latter is constructed using double negation, '없지는' and '않아요'.

What is the difference between the two and when do you use No. 2 in place of No. 1?

Comment: Could the second be, "That I have no girlfriend is not true."?

Comment: Maybe like "It's not that I don't have a girlfriend, but...".  If you were sincere about it, you would just say it - "I have a girlfriend".

Comment: Are you only interested in cases where '여자친구' is considered singular? My local Korean thought that without context being known, a possible obvious translation for 나는 여자친구가 없지는  않아요 would be "I do *have* female friends..." (emphasising that you don't *not* have them). This meaning doesn't have the connotation of unsatisfactoriness mentioned by 1ambda and lhrkknd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hear the two as...

> I have a girlfriend.

...versus...

> It's not exactly that I don't have a girlfriend...

Comment: Can this be compared with the 'actually, contrary to expectations' meaning  here: http://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/2185/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-%E3%84%B4-in-the-v%EC%A7%84-%EC%95%8A%EB%8B%A4-structure ?

Comment: Not quite that, but in your answer there you mentioned another meaning, _not 'very' or 'particularly' true_. It is of this type. Then on top of this, the context (the shadiness of being ambiguous about whether one has a girlfriend) adds tones of hesitation or complication.

Answer (score 3):

The second sentence means

> I have a girl friend but I am not happy about that. It would be better
>   to find another girl.

In this case, you can say in Korean, *있으나 마나* (= It is not very helpful even if I have it)

Answer (score 3):

없지는 않아요 means there is what you want but not entirely or not recommendedly.

In that case, the man has a girl friend but she usualy does not satisfy the man, or could be a part time lover.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @1ambda's opinion, but there is a slight difference with me.
I think his translation is a little rude and arrogant.
My opinion is,

> I have a girl friend, but she is just friend for now.

This means my girl friend is not very close, so I can't sure she is 'my' girl friend.